# Apply commands to variables in datasets in a list?

Tags: r

I have a list that contains 475 datasets with 14 identical columns. The "timestamp" column gives a date and time, but the formatting is not consistent from one dataset to the next. I need to get the formatting uniform across all datasets, but can't figure out how to apply a command to each "timestamp" variable.

I'm relatively new to R and feel like I'm missing something obvious... Help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnzgy.png)

Comment: Can you describe what kinds of formats are there?

Comment: Btw, that image is really not helpful. Even if we ignore it's an image -- all the timestamps are NA!

Comment: Going by the image, your `timestamp` variable is already `POSIXct`, which are not really associated with a format at all (though they have a default printing method when looking at them in R). You're going to have to clarify what you are working with.

Comment: You might also try `tidyr::unnest(YOUR_LIST, .id = "source_file")` to make it a flat file.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to know whether this will do the trick without access to the data. Try using the package `lubridate`. It can output different formats but it will accept any POSIXct and POSIXt. You'll have to loop over all of your 475 datasets. Here's a guess at a solution with the `lubridate` function `ymd_hms()`:

```
library(lubridate)

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  files[[i]]$timestamp <- ymd_hms(files[[i]]$timestamp)
}
```

This will format all of the timestamps as "2018-11-28 17:08:00", for example. See [this cheatsheet](https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/lubridate.pdf) for more formats.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info. I was after the basic code to implement *any* command on a variable (within a list within a list) and the date issue was one of several things I needed to mess with. The for loop did the trick. Thanks!